# if statment terminates with exit(); in c

Tags: c

i write code in c and i want to terminate if statement i use.

```
exit();
```

function it works but it will create new problem.

```
getch();
```

function stop working in my code and the output wont stay on screen it just flash and disappeared.
here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cono.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(void)
{
 int a,b;
 printf("enter a");
 scanf("%d",&a);
 printf("enter b");
 scanf("%d",&b);
 if(a==1,b<=8)
 {
  printf("you");
  exit(0);
  }
 if(a==2,5<b<=10)
 {
  printf("you");
 else
 printf("me");
 }
 getch();
 }
```

Comment: That's because the [`exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) function terminates the process immediately. It doesn't return.

Comment: `exit()` terminates the running process. How do you expect `getch` being able to do something, if the very process that would call it gets terminated long before. Just use structured programming or (god forbid) a goto.

Comment: Also, your conditions are wrong. With `a==1,b<=8` do you mean `a==1 && b<=8`? Perhaps you should [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start all over.

Comment: `if(a==1,b<=8)` and `if(a==2,5<b<=10)` what do you expect these tests to do?

Comment: place a `getch()` before  `exit()`.

Comment: **How do these questions even receive upvotes!**

Comment: i am beginner in the case i write if(a==1,b<=8) in my code i think the control first check the value of a and then b and then run if condition but i think i did not know the accurate syntax to write that can anyone give me correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the concept of the function `exit(int)`. The `exit` function terminates the current calling process and returns control to the Operating System, which in your case means that it terminates the execution of `main`.

Comment: **"exit() can be used to stop a loop, but it cannot be used to stop an if condition, since it does not constitute a calling process unit"**. -  What do you mean by this ?

Comment: Reading the beginning of the question: "i write code in c and i want to terminate if statement i use." it seemed to me that what he intended to do with the  `exit()` command was to stop running the rest of commands inside the scope of the if statement.

Comment: I think you are confused between `break` and `exit`. Is it ?

Comment: You are right, the example I used would be true for `break`, not `exit`. I will edit it.